# Integrating a function of φ and cosθ over the entire solid angle in spherical coordinates.

Tags: integration, solid-angle

I found this integral in a book:

[link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhCrV.png)

The integrated function is a phase function or just a probability density function.

I don't understand why instead of
 *dω' = sinθ dφ dθ*
 in this case 
*dω' = dφ dcosθ*.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$ \frac{d \cos\theta}{d\theta} = -\sin \theta, $$ and I suppose the minus sign is absorbed in $p(\cos \theta)$.

If the above is incorrect, please comment more details pertaining to the question.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems to explain it.

Comment: The minus sign is absorbed by the switching of integration order $$\int_0^{\pi} \sin{\theta} \mathrm d \theta = \int_1^{-1} - \mathrm d \cos{\theta} = \int_{-1}^1 \mathrm d \cos{\theta}$$

Comment: Yes. Saw that now. Thanks.